# How to check records for two conditions in one column in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle21c

Scenario:

1. Record should not be available in TABLE1 table with flag of the record as "A"
2. If loan_no is available in TABLE1 the flag of the record should be "D" and date of the
   maximum record available in TABLE1 should be less than 1st March 2023

TABLE1:

```
loan_no  flag   amt    dt

913813    A     100   01-01-2023
913813    A     200   02-01-2023
913813    D     300   03-01-2023
813713    D     600   04-01-2023
813713    D     8700  05-01-2023
813713    D     560   06-01-2023
123678    D     150   07-01-2023
567345    P     789   08-01-2023
567345    D     789   09-01-2023
912353    D     454   10-09-2023
```

Expected result:

```
loan_no  flag   amt    dt

813713    D     560   06-01-2023
123678    D     150   07-01-2023
```

The query should be in select clause because I am joining this query to another three tables. So cost should not get high for performance .

Here are DDL and DML:

```
create table TABLE1 (
loan_no varchar2(200),
flag varchar2(200),
amt varchar2(200),
dt  date
);
/
    
insert into table1 values ('913813','A','100',to_date('01-01-2023','dd-mm-yyyy'));
insert into table1 values ('913813','A','200',to_date('02-01-2023','dd-mm-yyyy'));
insert into table1 values ('913813','D','300',to_date('03-01-2023','dd-mm-yyyy'));
insert into table1 values ('813713','D','600',to_date('04-01-2023','dd-mm-yyyy'));
insert into table1 values ('813713','D','8700',to_date('05-01-2023','dd-mm-yyyy'));
insert into table1 values ('813713','D','560',to_date('06-01-2023','dd-mm-yyyy'));
insert into table1 values ('123678','D','150',to_date('07-01-2023','dd-mm-yyyy'));
insert into table1 values ('567345','P','789',to_date('08-01-2023','dd-mm-yyyy'));
insert into table1 values ('567345','D','789',to_date('09-01-2023','dd-mm-yyyy'));
insert into table1 values ('912353','D','454',to_date('10-01-2023','dd-mm-yyyy'));
```

Comment: your resultset doesn't fit your condition 913813     has a Flag A, so it makes all no sense

Comment: Why should the row `567345,D,789,09-01-2023` not appear in the result?

Comment: Is this what you want to do?: https://dbfiddle.uk/yNJJQmOL

Comment: @Jonas Metzler . how can we use it without the "WITH" clause ?

Comment: Hi , Sorry if u don't understand . i only need the record with flag as D  and its maximum date .if a loan number has other than "D" it should skip the loan number

Comment: See here: https://dbfiddle.uk/AEXvv2nt, but 1) why not use the `CTE`, 2) could you please try out the query and tell us if it is correct for your use case?

Comment: @jonas Metzler  Thanks for the query .. i will check and confirm. and one more thing what do you mean by CTE

Answer (score 1):

You can use analytical window functions to generate conditional columns and then use them to filter rows -

```
SELECT loan_no, flag, amt, dt
  FROM (SELECT t1.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY loan_no ORDER BY dt DESC) rn,
                     COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN flag = 'D' then 1 else 0 end) OVER(PARTITION BY loan_no) cnt
          FROM table1 t1
         WHERE dt < '01-mar-2023'
       )
WHERE cnt = 1
  AND rn = 1
ORDER BY dt;
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/_kIVtAMJ)